# Как разрезать картинку на части в pictureBox

Tags: c#

Помогите решить такую проблему:
- загружаю картинку "dds", подключая "DevIL.dll".

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap Loadddsimage = DevIL.DevIL.LoadBitmap(@"C:\a\test.dds");
```

В этом файле большое количество иконок - примерно 2000 штук, но они склеены.

Ширина будет ~80, высота возможно даже в двое больше. Размер каждой картинки примерно 16x16.

Разрезанные изображения хочу поместить либо в файл, либо в тот же `picturebox`,с границами или отступами между ними.

Не имею представления это можно реализовать?

Comment: все картинки одного размера? склеены без промежутков?

Comment: Да все одного размера.И промежутков нет.

Comment: в цикле по количеству картинок рисуй их в отдельный image, который сохраняй в файл

Comment: Подсказка логичная.Но если бы я знал как то мне не составило бы труда создать цикл.Можешь есть где почитать на эту тему?

Comment: например вот: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms142041(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Можно так: `var img = Loadddsimage.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16), Loadddsimage.PixelFormat);` Задаёшь в цикле прямоугольник и всё.

Comment: Проанализировал,можно совсем обойтись без разделения.Теперь вопрос в другом...как я выше говорил:картинка очень большая,само собой ее в picturebox полностью не как не поместить.Сделал Scroll но при его передвижение ужасные лаги и через какое товремя вылетает ошибка связанная с system.drawing.dll...Как можно реализовать нормальный скролл?

Comment: Насколько большая? Конкретно: в пикселах, в байтах (как на диске, так и в оперативке).